# Thinkpad X61 and SSD with MiniPCI-E interface

Tags: laptop, ssd, minipci

I've got Thinkpad X61 (model [7674-gs3](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/quickPath.do?quickPathEntry=7674GS3)). I've got an empty MiniPCI slot (which in other models is filled with WWAN or Intel Turbo Memory)... so I thought I could try inserting an SSD disk there, for example one of [OCZ MiniPCI SSD disks](http://www.ocztechnology.com/products/solid_state_drives/ocz_minipci_express_ssd-sata_).

I seems that the BIOS might not accept this card as not authorized. Also, it is a full-size MiniPCI card, so I'm not sure if it will fit there.

Has anybody tried this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not fit. I just purchased one of these cards, apperently the cards are full sized Mini-PCIe cards. the free slot in the X61 is a single sided card for WWAN or WLAN. I just wasted money trying this. I should have googled it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it with a Thinkpad, but I have tried various Mini PCI / Express type cards such as the one you have showed and all of them have been lousy.

It should not need to be "authorised" however, the machine may not be able to boot as some emulate a RAID type card then make the drive available through additional drivers (when Windows has loaded).

Anyway, I can't say for sure on your model, but every single one I have tried that uses a expansion card seems to have gone wrong somewhere or is a nightmare to set up then comes back a week later with some problem... I just wouldn't touch them.